# Query a count of most recent records with a specific value

Tags: mysql

The table I'm trying to query records the outcome of a specific phone call that was made. So each row has a case_id, last_called (date/timestamp), an outcome (SIQdisp1_a), and then a few other pieces of info (batch number, employee number).

Here is the syntax I'm using currently:

```
SELECT 
DATE(last_called), COUNT(SIQdisp1_a), Access.batch_number
FROM
disposition_log
    LEFT JOIN
Access ON disposition_log.case_id = Access.identifier
WHERE
SIQdisp1_a = 14
    AND case_id NOT LIKE 'test%'
    AND batch_number = 171205
GROUP BY DATE(last_called);
```

So this will count the number of outcomes per day that = 14 (and are in the appropriate batch). What I need to do, is to modify it such that it only counts the outcome if it is the most recent outcome for that case_id. for instance, if a person was called 3 times in one day, and all 3 times the outcome is equal to 14, I only need that to count once. The syntax I have currently would add all 3 instances of a 14 to the final count.

I've tried using

```
SELECT MAX(DATE(last_called), COUNT(SIQdisp1_a)
```

but that returns the same results as the original syntax.  I feel like I'm missing something basic here. . . any suggestions are appreciated!

Edit (Including Sample Data):

```
case_id    last_called          SIQdisp1_a
1002175    2018-02-16 12:42:36  14
1002175    2018-02-16 13:20:11  14
1005695    2018-02-15 12:00:00  14
1003018    2018-02-15 12:00:00  13
1003018    2018-02-15 11:59:00  14
1005974    2018-02-15 14:33:33  14
```

Sorry that I didn't include sample data the first time around. With this sample data, each row is a call to somebody (case_id), the date/time of the call (last_called) and the outcome of that call (SIQdisp1_a). What I need, is a count of the number of 14's per day, but the 14 must be the most recent entry for that ID. So in the dataset above, the result would be something like:

```
Date(last_called)    COUNT(SIQdisp1_a)
2018-02-16           1 
2018-02-15           2
```

So for 2-16, the count would be 1 because I ONLY want to count the most recent record. If that most recent record is a 14, it gets added to the total. For 2-15, it's a total of 2 because the most recent outcome for cases 1005974 and 1005695 is 14. Case 1003018 should not be counted because even though there was a 14 at 11:49, there was a call at 12:00 with an outcome of 13.  The syntax I posted at the top counts EVERY instance of 14 it sees, it doesn't look for the most recent.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Sounds like you want distinct: `COUNT(distinct SIQdisp1_a)`

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @William_Wilson they'd only ever get 1 as a result.

Comment: @Uueerdo I may have misunderstood what the OP was looking for. A better description would help, as the "most recent outcome" will always be a single item; meaning this isn't a counting question at all, but I took the (possibly incorrect) leap that they meant distinct outcomes because they specifically want to rule out duplicates.

Comment: @William_Wilson agree on the question needing clarified; the way it is worded I would _guess_ `COUNT(DISTINCT case_id)` _might_ be closer to what they need.

Comment: @Strawberry I tried to provide an MCVE, thank you for the guidance

Comment: @William_Wilson I really didn't do a very good job explaining what I need, I apologize. I hope my edits and sample data will help clarify!

Comment: 'Tried'? well, when you succeed let us know.

Answer (score 0):

1 option with a subquery:

`select date(last_called), count(case_id) from <table> where (case_id,last_called) in (select case_id, max(last_called) from <table> group by case_id,date(last_called)) and SIQdisp1_a=14 group by date(last_called);`